# Are there any blockexplorers that will track RingCT usage after the v4 fork?

Tags: ringct, privacy, block-explorer

[Statistics on mixin data](http://moneroblocks.info/stats) is useful to anyone interested in privacy levels of Monero network transactions. I would like to track what percentage of transactions use RingCT between v4 activation and v5 enforcement.

Will there be RingCT statistics available starting the first day after the [v4 fork](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/will-there-be-a-january-hard-fork-for-ringct)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [Onion Monero](http://xmrblocksvckbwvx.onion/) Blockchain Explorer supports RingCT. [Currently it is](https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer):

> the only explorer supporting Monero testnet network and RingCT,

More blockexplorers may add support in the coming weeks but I am not aware of any specific announcements.